# Are we cleaning up our member database sometime?

Tags: support, users

Is there a process to delete/deactivate members with no activity for a very long time?

I came across a user nickname, "Mike", that has no traffic at all and has been a member for one year and three months.

This has some impact on the Stack Overflow database, doesn't it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, there is a cleanup process of old users, but rep and existing content become a factor, not just the *last visited* time.

You can find the details on the SO Blog entry from 2009 [When Is An Account “Abandoned”?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/), but in it [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) lays out the 2 major points that are looked at:

> We came up with these two rules of thumb. If..
>
> 1. the user has not visited the site in six months
>    **AND**
> 2. the user has not done anything of significance, ever
>
> .. their accounts are effectively abandoned. We don’t believe those users are ever coming back.

And a bit further in the post Jeff explains the specific criteria

> We **delete cookie-based unregistered accounts** when:
>
> 1. The user has not visited Stack Overflow in six months
>    **AND**
> 2. The user has less than 50 reputation, and no visible (not-deleted) posts
>
> We **delete OpenID registered accounts** when:
>
> 1. The user has not visited Stack Overflow in six months
>    **AND**
> 2. The user has only 1 reputation, no visible posts, and no other accounts on the network

[Shog9 also adds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146452/182513) that the cleanup process only deletes a handful at a time due to the vast quantity of qualifying accounts, which is could be why the account you saw has no activity but hasn't been deleted (assuming it did have 1 rep).

This is all that is done.  Jeff's goes into some detail as to why this is all that is done, but the short version is there is little reason to do so.  Accounts on Stack Exchange are extremely lightweight so it really isn't a drain on resources to keep them around.

Beyond Jeff's criteria, you have to understand that deleting a user is probably much more difficult (and painful) than keeping it, and it will have an impact on other users of the site.

When a user is deleted,

1. Questions that meet specific score criterion (<0 net score) [are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199814/why-did-community-user-delete-this-meta-question-where-multiple-answers-had-up-v).  Any user who answered that question stands to lose the rep they earned for that question.
2. When a user is deleted, [**all** of their votes are thrown away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it/126471#126471).  Depending on the user and how much they voted, this could result in many users losing hundreds or thousands of rep points as a result.

When considering this, it seems a lot easier for the system and better for the site to just leave the account alone and make the user responsible for deleting their account if they don't want it anymore.

Comment: seems like user 1 is still around http://stackoverflow.com/users/1  ***user 6 is not found!!!!*** http://stackoverflow.com/users/6 neither is user 7.. good ole [Sneakers O'Toole](http://stackoverflow.com/users/10/sneakers-otoole) still has an account, lol. Only 3764804 accounts to go through. Will keep you updated!!!

Comment: based on [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209516) until 6 hours ago 526828 accounts have been deleted, assuming the userid's are generated from a stable sequence generator...

Comment: In the rules of thumb, what is considered *"anything of significance"*?

Comment: @RichardScriven given the actual criteria, I'm am going to guess that it is one of the 2nd criteria... either `The user has less than 50 reputation, and no visible (not-deleted) posts` for unregistered users and `The user has only 1 reputation, no visible posts, and no other accounts on the network` for registered users

Comment: @VotetoClose I just looked at a batch of the first users and I am amazed how many of them do still regularly come here (or at least have been here in the last two days).

Comment: I created my account around 2 years back and did not do anything for nearly two years. That a tiny bit more than 6 months :P. I'm curious why I am still alive.

Comment: Read the sentence under the second quote again @Krumia.

Comment: @Ben: I definitely did not have anything under my belt. Probably it was the occasional visits that saved me.

Comment: The deletion script was 237k (see linked questions to the link) accounts behind almost 2 years ago when I made that request @Krumia; it's unlikely anyone will ever be deleted.