# Spam in "about me"

Tags: discussion, spam, profile-page

I just had a look at some of the spam-flags I raised some time ago. In the course of this I stumbled upon [this userprofile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744716/user3744716): The account has no (undeleted) posts and its "about me" contains 100% pure and untainted spam. I know it's rather unlikely anyone will stumble over this profile (if it wasn't for this post) and the userprofile isn't exactly required to be on topic. But shouldn't the account still be deleted - or at least have its "about me" removed?

Comment: You can pretty much put anything you want in the "About Me" section—including spam—unless it is blatantly offensive to some person or group. So yeah, I mean, if this is simply a spam-bot account, it might be appropriate for a moderator to delete it. Otherwise, we tend to just leave them alone.

Comment: Meh, the account had a deleted spam post and no other productive activity, making it a candidate for destruction. So... FOOM.

Comment: related: [I have found 16,809 similar, inappropriate(?) user profiles. There are more. Now what?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421453/11107541), [Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746/997587)

Comment: *"You can pretty much put anything you want in the 'About Me' section—including spam—unless it is blatantly offensive to some person or group."* From personal experience I can say with confidence that this is completely untrue (unless somebody redefined "blatantly" to hold the same meaning as "slightly" now). See [here](https://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/good_riddance_stack_overflow.shtml) and [here](https://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/social_justice_overflow.shtml) for context.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The account is a spam account that has been abandoned. There is really nothing that needs to be done about this account.

Nothing in that profile is actually clickable. No Google rank is generated from it. Practically no one will ever find it, as there are no visible posts or other activity for that account anymore. Many such accounts are [automatically deleted after a few years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310446/as-per-the-new-data-retention-policy-when-will-inactive-accounts-now-be-deleted/310516#310516), so the system will, over time, purge itself from accounts like these.

For *active* accounts, we tolerate a lot more in the About Me section including commercial promotion; it is the one place you get to let your hair down a little. For low-reputation accounts all links in profiles are marked as `rel="nofollow"`; accounts with 2k rep+ [have the `nofollow` marker removed for their *one* website link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171503/how-can-i-get-dofollow-link-in-my-stack-overflow-profile/171509#171509).

That said, if you can find an account that is active with an *About Me* that is blatantly offensive to large groups of people or directly attacking someone in a hateful manner, feel free to flag a post or comment by that user to alert the moderators of the section, and they can deal with it.

Comment: Can we not autoban spammers? If their posts are deleted as spams, their (network) profiles should be checked out too: https://stackoverflow.com/users/22072366/surbhi-roy

Comment: @mplungjan that’s not something that moderators can do. For specific cases we can ask the CM team to apply a network-wide ban. For the specific account there is no content left anywhere and so would not be worth the effort

Comment: Ah, What looks like a link in here about page is not a link that will generate backlinks.

Comment: @mplungjan: that's the *Nothing in that profile is actually clickable* part of my answer.

Comment: That was what I meant

Answer (score 10):

FWIW, I found a whole network of these accounts when searching for my name in users:
https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=ashelly

As far as I can tell, all but 2 were created soley to post spam in the "About Me" box.

Comment: 5 years later, they are still there. The auto-delete mentioned in the other answer doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Auto-deleting of accounts has [changed  since then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310446/as-per-the-new-data-retention-policy-when-will-inactive-accounts-now-be-deleted/310516#310516), and in 2014 the [deletion process was lagging behind massively](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266177/are-we-cleaning-up-our-member-database-sometime/266178), so some of the accounts could still be around. However, most of the accounts in that search are newer than this answer.