# I have found 16,809 similar, inappropriate(?) user profiles. There are more. Now what?

Tags: discussion, spam, specific-user

I've found two pools of users whose profiles are probably machine generated. Their creation dates spike near certain days. The users don't seem to have done anything (no posts, no comments, last access date is the same as creation date, etc.), so there isn't much "active" harm being done, but...

This seems like a strange thing to allow to happen here.

Note: [In 2018, accounts that had existed for over two years without doing anything* got deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310516/997587), and prior to that, automatic deletion used to be done routinely. The users I found probably meet the criteria for deletion. If there's a future batch deletion, any profiles here which meet the criteria will probably get deleted.

Data about the users can be found in [**this group of SEDE Queries**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1670610/spam-like-user-profiles). It shows all the profiles, and graphs the creation date spikes.

### User Pool #1: "美女妹子能上门着叫"

Most (all?) of the users' display names contain "美女妹子能上门着叫". I can't read Chinese, but [Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) says their username means "*Beautiful girls can call at the door*", which is somewhat of an eyebrow raiser and might be walking some lines with the terms of service / code of conduct.

The profiles' "About Me" sections don't seem to all have identical content, but they seem to be following a pattern:

- The first part seems like an advertisement for an [escort service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escort_agency),
- then some kind of news report about the [Regional Comprehensive Economic Partnership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Comprehensive_Economic_Partnership) (which I don't know anything about, but seems like a weirdly specific topic),
- then some tabloid / gossipy news,
- then what might be an excerpt from a book / poetry.

### User Pool #2: "服务真在妹子真找一晚上电话多少"

Google Translate: "*service is really in the girl really looking for a night how many calls*"

The "About Me" content follows a similar pattern to the previous one, but instead of the RCEP, it has "AsianInvent2020".

### Stack Overflow's Acceptable Use Policy

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy).

> - Spam. Users that *do not publish meaningful content*, use deceptive means to generate revenue or traffic, or whose primary purpose is affiliate marketing, will be suspended.
> - Mass Registration and Automation. Accounts that are registered automatically or systematically will be removed and access will be permanently suspended.
> - Sexually Explicit Material. Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

If you don't think the above two pools count toward "sexually explicit", then how about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20127606), from [a pool of 461](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1675373)?

### To Be Continued?

There are more. [Here's a SEDE graph of spikes in created users with "。" or "，" in their profiles' About Me sections](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1670620/spikes-in-created-users-with-chinese-punctuation-in-their-about-me-sections#graph).

A different heuristic I found recently was to search by Avatar Url. Lots of these groups of yucky profiles have the same gravatar within the group (maybe they're [using the same emails and somehow got a same hash-salt value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17443/997587)?). I discovered this by modifying [a query rene made](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1602299) in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379303/#comment1265792_379303) to an MSE post ([Why do so many users have no hash value for their identicon, resulting in the default identicon being used for each of them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379303/997587)). Here's the modified SEDE query based on the one rene made: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1702306/2070941/. Update: that probably no longer works now (see ["We're regenerating all identicons"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389123/997587)). But I've found another pretty good way: by finding accounts with the same website URL ([here's a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1749339)).

Comment: see MSE: [Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w)

Comment: SE's official policy is "ignore it". We've asked for SE to make changes which would substantially minimize the impact (e.g. don't publicly display profiles for users with < X rep, where X is quite low, like 5 or 10). We, mods across the SE network, have asked for better tools to deal with it. Mods could fairly easily find such profiles. We could destroy them *on our site only*, but the user could just *immediately* recreate the profile on that site from the SE account and have back everything that was in the profile (i.e. any profile spam, etc.).

Comment: Please *don't* flag for these, unless they are *exceptionally egregious* (e.g. child porn). [For those that are *exceptionally egregious*, please do flag.] If moderators want to spend time on these, then we can find hundreds of thousands of them on our own, and it's a *lot* faster for us to handle them that way than the one or small number which you might fit in a flag.

Comment: Lot's of us are quite frustrated with these, but to *actually* deal with the problem requires changes to the system which would need to be made by SE. So far, SE has not spent time on making such changes, although there are hints that SE might take a small step in the direction which would allow moderators to be effective in at least getting rid of them on the individual sites where they are a moderator, if the moderator wants to spend quite a bit of time handling them.

Comment: Makyen thanks for responding. Out of curiosity, is there a reason you don't put your response in an answer post instead of in comments?

Comment: Well, bots or not, still "new" user accounts and those look fine when you show some growth charts for the next business presentation.

Comment: @starball Lack of available time, mostly. To make what I'd consider to be a real answer would require me doing a notable amount research to dig out references from various meta posts and separate out what's in mod-private areas vs what's public on MSO, MSE, and other metas. Me commenting is *mostly* me expressing frustration with the current situation.

Comment: Policy: Profile only, with no activity: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297999/282094 or enough activity to activate links in profile: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1323/282094

Comment: ***16809 Accounts*** Nearly seventeen THOUSAND obviously abusive accounts. I think "It not hurting anyone" is not a valid excuse not to nuke the ever-living crap out of such blatant spam. It's not difficult to hide a user's about me section when they have low rep...

Comment: We just have to restrict the low rep users. I.e. they need 5 - 15 rep to be able to change the generated name (`user12345`) and maybe 25 rep to change their bio.

Comment: @Lino I honestly don't remember how account registration worked, but I wouldn't restrict usernames like that. New users have enough trouble asking questions as it is without an anonymized profile. (At very least allow _setting_ the username, but restrict when it's shown to above a rep treshold)

Comment: Eight views in total, according to the query, most of which are probably yours.  Seems like the only ones wasting their time are the account creators themselves.

Comment: The characters you're searching on in your query are also used in Japanese, so I'm concerned about false positives in this context.  (Note that this is the CJK plane in Unicode, so more than just Chinese characters exist here.)  While I totally get that there's an issue with all of these accounts here, I'm really concerned about painting a specific group with an overly broad brush in this case...

Comment: These accounts might not be causing harm (yet) on SO but they are potentially being used for harming other servers, with SO being used as a middleware. It could also be used as a demonstration to sell the tool script for mass-creating those profiles. The user pools described resemble similar spam accounts created by Asian-based hackers on Facebook. Such accounts lay dormant for some time until they are massive enough to cause damage to their intended target i.e. overwhelming APIs, mass-creating accounts using cross-site (OAuth) login, mass-reporting target accounts, etc.

Comment: Do they have the blue verified icon (TM)? Did they pay $8?

Comment: @Cerbrus and how does one stumble across them?

Comment: nobody_at_stack_exchange_inc_cares.gif

Comment: Elon Musk will purchase SO, require an 8$/m subscription to use the site, and bot accounts won't be the major issue anymore.

Comment: @Makyen *"Please don't flag for these, unless they are exceptionally egregious (e.g. child porn)."* - Going by the automated translation, there is a real possibility that the spammer is engaged in trafficking people for sex, or spamming on behalf of somebody who is. I would hope that that is egregious enough for Stack Exchange to act on this.

Comment: @kaya3 At least for the ones identified here for which I've used Google Translate on the profile contents, they sound like typical spam for escort services, which we see *all the time*, both in profiles and in posts. There's a notable difference between those and the ones which appear to be trafficking. If it appeared to be trafficking, then, yes, that would be something for which we'd like to see a flag, even for it being in a profile. If it's in posts and it's spam of any sort, then a spam flag on the post is appropriate (and the more egregious ones can get a custom flag).

Comment: The discrepancy between "things on which SE Inc acts" and "things on which SE Inc does _not_ act" is astonishing. Sure, saying that there is no "active" harm in these accounts is technically true (as is saying that there is no "active" harm in handgranades on children's playground). But I cannot even _imagine_ the attack vectors of several thousand fake accounts. I'm not surprised. Just deeply, deeply disappointed. So ... nothing new here.

Comment: Could these accounts be used for the equivalent of a denial of service attack and/or  a means of blk spamming the system when desired at some future time. (eg only Invasion of Taiwan or whatever ? ) || Is this a concern? || Is there any reason NOT to auto delete these accounts? || WHY is there good reason for these to still exist?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Now what?

On Stack Overflow, probably nothing. I'm not a moderator there anytime soon. On smaller sites, it depends. It doesn't look good when your new users page is full of crap. It isn't welcoming to your community when the [Recent Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) is dominated by "Autobiographer" badges awarded to spammers.

On [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions), the flag load is light enough that I can spend 30 minutes on doing busy work each day. There are some custom built queries, apps, chat bots and user scripts that assist moderators to find these profiles and then reset the username, clear the profile, push the changes to all sites, suspend the user and destroy the account.

A quick inspection reveals that the accounts you found didn't cause havoc yet on Stack Apps. I do have a similar case that I have no problem with sharing. These [accounts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackapps/query/1666726/accounts-to-revisit-for-promotion) were created while I was actively monitoring the site and I literally nuked accounts seconds after they were created. The problem? The spammer was able to create accounts quicker than I could nuke them. The mod-tooling for this task is so underpowered that for 1 destroyed account 5 new ones were created. Just FYI: moderator actions are rate-limited, especially in this area.

There was some hope that Stack Exchange would be willing to clean-up this specific network-wide profile spam mess, but in the end, it is left to the site moderators again. I know of at least one moderator that also cleaned up the spam flood I referred to. <s>I'm in the process of destroying all these accounts on Stack Apps</s>. Those accounts have been "handled".

We're reassured again and again by Stack Exchange staff that these spam profiles are only a local nuisance. The user profile is not indexed<sup>1</sup> so having 16 thousand pages link to a website won't help their SEO ranking. From that point of view, I can understand this issue doesn't get any priority to get fixed soon™. We have to do it with the manual labor of willing site moderators, now and then supported by the CM team. It is far from ideal.

Now what? Wait for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514). Hold my beer, I have some accounts to nuke.

---

<sub>1.  I don't think SE is right with their non-index argument. I don't believe it is true as I have seen instances where profiles were found, by me and by several others .... but I can only go with the official reading until someone at the company admits they made a mistake. They can be forgiven as soon as that happens.</sub>

Comment: "I have some accounts to nuke." but "I'm not a moderator". How do you do it then? I don't get it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Each quote applies to a different site? rene is a moderator on stackapps.

Comment: "_Just FYI: moderator actions are rate-limited, specially in this area_". Well to that I can say UUUUUGGGGGHHHHHHHH.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні I take it you don't remember the last time a mod script went rogue.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні kinda makes sense to rate-limit mods, not as much as normal users, but still. You wouldn't want somebody to get up on the wrong side of the bed one day and nuke thousands of profiles for whatever reason, or mess up an automated bot doing the same thing. I don't think the problem is about the rate limiting here :\

Comment: Are you sure the user profiles are not indexed? I remember finding them in Google search

Comment: @wizz (and Marco) what are we even doing if we can't trust mods not to abuse their powers? I assumed there was an assumption that mods are above all that, so "mod abuses powers" should be the exceptioniest of exceptions. In other words nerfing normal mod activities is the harmfully dumb choice in my opinion. Yes, if once every 5 years something goes wrong, an employee will have to clean it up. We'll still be better off. Discipline the mod, unmod them, give mods a sandbox to debug scripts in, whatever. (Side note: I'm not a huge fan of "mod scripts". Make it easy and fast for humans to mod.)

Comment: Just an FYI: Mods are permitted to use userscripts to automate actions which they would normally perform while they are active using their browser (i.e. where the actions have immediate oversight). However, bots (e.g. operations which are not directly and actively overseen) are not permitted to be run with moderator credentials. While the difference between these isn't clearly defined, the intent is that it's not permitted to not have a human in the loop actively instigating and overseeing the actions.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that there are several hundred moderators across the SE network on almost two hundred different sites. So, even if the only reason to have *some* rate limits was to limit the damage which could be done by someone with legitimate access to moderator credentials, it would still be reasonable to have some rate limits. However, that's not the only possible issue. Just like any restricted access, one also has to consider that it's *possible* for someone to gain illegitimate access. In such cases, rate limits, particularly on destructive actions, are quite helpful to limit damage.

Comment: @Dharman I didn't say SE is right with their non-index argument. I don't believe it is true as I have seen instances where profiles were found so .... but I can only go with the official reading until someone admits they made a mistake. They can be forgiven as soon as that happens.

Comment: @rene or 6 to 8 weeks later.

Comment: @Dharman I just Googled my account name with site:stackexchange.com and found a few of my profiles...